# Grub menu doesn't appear

Tags: 12.04, boot, grub2

I'm using windows 7 and I installed Ubuntu 12.04 along side with it by creating a new 60 GB partition. It installed perfectly and then I restart the PC. I can't see the grub menu that let me to choose the operating systems. My monitor shows

> unsupported input

Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

This post is a bit old, but I was having a similar issue, and it seems the OP never got an answer which helped.  Like I said, my situation was similar, but my monitor reported that it was `not optimal`, and displayed nothing.

The menu was there, I know because I could arrow down and press Enter and the boot up would be different (i.e. 4 down was Windows on my PC).  I did a little research and ended up updating `/boot/grub/grub.cf` setting the line as follows:

FROM (was):

```
set gfxmode=auto
```

TO:

```
set gfxmode=1024x768
```

Saved and rebooted. The menu now shows. Hope this helps.

*Note*: You have to `sudo` to edit the file.

Answer (score 0):

You can select operating systems before you get to the grub menu, or at least you should be able to.  On my wubi install I have to select Ubuntu at boot before grub appears.  Just select windows 7 before you get to grub.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. Boot into Ubuntu.
2. Go to the Terminal by searching "Terminal" in the dash.
3. Type `sudo gedit /etc/default/grub` in the terminal and type your password if prompted.
4. Locate the line `GRUB_TIMEOUT=0`.  Change the value from 0 to 10 then save the file and close it.  GRUB will now let you choose the Operating system for 10 seconds when you boot your computer.  You should see `GRUB_TIMEOUT=10` instead of 0.
5. Go back to the terminal window (you didn't close that, didn't you?) and type `sudo update-grub` in the terminal.  Type your password if prompted, then wait until the task had been processed.
6. Reboot and test!

Comment: It is not working friend.I still haven't see the grub menu.

Comment: For the "Unsupported input", Do you see it before the computer splash screen?  If you saw that beforre your computer splash screen, then there is something wrong with your monitor, not Ubuntu.

Comment: use gksudo not sudo. Using sudo on graphical apps can be dangerous.