# How to remove ubuntu and install xp?

Tags: installation, dvd, windows-xp, bios

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Switching OS from Ubuntu to XP?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/155263/switching-os-from-ubuntu-to-xp)

dvd player works during start up, but stops after few seconds.
then ubuntu starts up.
so I can't install xp.
I changed bios to dvd on 1.
I heard that I could loosen the cmos battery, but I dare not doing that.
Is there an other way?

Comment: Have you saw [this question](http://askubuntu.com/q/133533/62483), maybe it can help you.

Answer (score 0):

are you using a built-in cdrom? check if you have any other options like TSSW or something similar in the boot order. somtimes the cdrom entry doesn't really represent your actual cdrom. 
just put everything you have in that boot order in front of your harddrive and see what happenes.

if that still does not help, try a differetn cdrom drive or a different bootable cd. it could be that the cd cannot be read by your cdrom for whatever reason (cdrom defective, dusty etc. or cd scratched).

Comment: don't know what tssw is. I'll try all possibilities of boot order. I know the xp cd is ok, it works on other pc's.  the drive is ok because it takes the life ubuntu cd without probs.